# Visual Studio 2013 WEB API template scaffolding fails when creating basic model and applying scaffold

Tags: asp.net-web-api, scaffolding, visual-studio-2013

Start up VS2013
Create basic WEB API project with defaults
Create basic model (ex. Person class with PersonId and PersonName properties)
Compile
Create Scaffold (pick WEB API with entities)

When I go to create the scaffold using all the defaults I get the error

Add Controller

Scaffolding Failed: WebApplication1.Models.WebApplication1Context is not a System.Data.Entity.DbContext class and does not contain a People property, so it cannot be used as the database context.

ANY IDEAS??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are using the Preview build which doesn't support this scenario. Can you please install Preview Refresh and confirm if this fixes your issue?

You can install Preview Refresh from:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39365

Comment: yes. that is correct.. wonder why such a simple bug got through the base install of vs2013 preview